# Swift内でjsonを呼び出す際の型がわかりません

Tags: xcode, json, swift4

swift4
xcode9.4.1

jsonの型をswift内で宣言する際の"型"がわかりません。
このjsonの場合どういう型を書けば良いでしょうか？

jsonは以下のようになっています。

```
{
    "calendar": {
        "month": {
            "jp": {
                "1" : "1月"
            },
            "en": {
                "1" : ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

そしてswift内でjsonを読み込むためのコードをいくつか書きました。

```
    let path : String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "language", ofType: "json")!
    let fileHandle : FileHandle = FileHandle(forReadingAtPath: path)!
    let data : NSData = fileHandle.readDataToEndOfFile() as NSData
    let json = NSString(data: data as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!
    do {
        let personalData: Data = json.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!

        ///この部分がAnyではなく上記Jsonを辞書型配列に直した時の型にしたい。
        let items = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: personalData) as! Any 
        print(items)
    } catch {
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

as! Any

ではなく

as! [String : Any]

として 順番に取り出してはいかがでしょうか。